# Rendering first three elements of an Observable Array using Knockout JS using splice() not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, odata

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC application in which I am using OData and Knockout JS View model to render the data on to the web page in a table.
Now I just want only first three elements of my observable Array to be rendered on the page. 
I tried using splice function of Knockout Js but it seems like not working.

I have the following code.

**Knockout Js View Model**

```
var CanadianCrudeViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.canadiancrudes = ko.observableArray();


 $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
        data: ko.toJSON(self.products),
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            self.datainput((ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (canadiancrude) {
                var obsCanadianCrude = {
                    Id: canadiancrude.Id,
                    Term: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Term),
                    Product: canadiancrude.Product,
                    Location: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Location),
                    Pipeline: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Pipeline),
                    BidCP: ko.observable(canadiancrude.BidCP),
                    BidVolume: ko.observable(canadiancrude.BidVolume),
                    Index: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Index),
                    Bid: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Bid),
                    Offer: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Offer),
                    OfferVolume: ko.observable(canadiancrude.OfferVolume),
                    OfferCP: ko.observable(canadiancrude.OfferCP),
                    Locked: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Locked),
                    Sequence: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Sequence),
                    TermID: ko.observable(canadiancrude.TermID),
                    Edit: ko.observable(false)
                }

                //self.datainput.splice(0, 1);
                self.watchModel(obsCanadianCrude, self.modelChanged);
                return obsCanadianCrude;
            })));
        }
    });



    $.getJSON('/odata/Canadiancrudes', function (data) {

        self.canadiancrudes(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (canadiancrude) {
            var obsCanadianCrude = {
                Id: canadiancrude.Id,
                Term: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Term),
                Product: canadiancrude.Product,
                Location: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Location),
                Pipeline: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Pipeline),
                BidCP: ko.observable(canadiancrude.BidCP),
                BidVolume: ko.observable(canadiancrude.BidVolume),
                Index: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Index),
                Bid: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Bid),
                Offer: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Offer),
                OfferVolume: ko.observable(canadiancrude.OfferVolume),
                OfferCP: ko.observable(canadiancrude.OfferCP),
                Locked: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Locked),
                Sequence: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Sequence),
                TermID: ko.observable(canadiancrude.TermID),
                Edit: ko.observable(false),
                selectedOptionValue: ko.observable(canadiancrude.Product)
            }
           // self.canadiancrudes.splice(1, 3);
            self.watchModel(obsCanadianCrude, self.modelChanged);
            return obsCanadianCrude;
        }))
    });

};

$(function () {
 viewModel.canadiancrudes.splice(0, 2);

        viewModel.canadiancrudes.push(obsCanadianCrude);

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


});
```

I am not sure I am doing it in correct way, is there any other better way I can do this using a computed function at least?

Answer (score 0):

Something like..

(Yes, I'm sure this code could be optimized)

```
vm.firstThree = ko.computed(function() {
  var ret = vm.canadiancrudes();
  // Cheap clone
  ret = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(ret))

  // Not sure if you'll need bounds checking here or not.
  ret = ret.slice(0, 2);

  return ret;
});
```

Comment: What was fromJS and toJS, they are not defined anywhere

Comment: From knockout itself, documented here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Not Working, still doesn't slice the array instead displays the entire array and throws up an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJS' of undefined